# Remerging two VirtualBox disks

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox disk (call it `Disk1`) which has been cloned into `Disk2`.

I still have the `Disk1` as it was at the moment I cloned it, but the `Disk2` have been modified since that moment.

At that moment, I ignored that I could use the same disk as base for different VMs, so I physically cloned it.

Now I'd want to create a differencing image between `Disk1` and `Disk2`, so that I can delete the cloned `Disk2` (17 GB) and use`Disk1` + differencing image instead.

Is that possibile?

Comment: Why not reclone?  It should be more reliable even if your could update deferentially.  I don't think you can do what you want with any standard (VirtualBox) methods.  I'm sure on a low level you could manipulate the file(s).

Comment: I mean reproduce your changes to Disk 1 that you made on DIsk 2 and the clone it again; or simply clone Disk 2 and integrate changes made to Disk 1.  Basically manually reconcile the changes and Virtualbox will not be able to do this for you.